# How do I specify the Product Feed when using the Product Catalog Batch API for Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

My question is about batch upload API for Product Catalogs. I'm doing a combination of daily batch API uploads and uploads through a CSV file. I'm starting to get conflicts because some products in the CSV have already been created via the batch upload API.
[image]

The part I'm interested in is this error message:

> Another product with the same id was already uploaded to this catalog in No feed

It looks like the batch upload API creates a **different** product feed titled "No feed". I'd really like the batch API products to go to the same feed. Is there any way to specify the feed in the API request or at least inspect the "No feed"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: I don’t understand, don’t you have to _specify_ the product catalog id in the API call to begin with? `/{product_catalog_id}/batch` is the path used for batch uploads - so what exactly did you use there?

Comment: Yes, I have to specify the `product_catalog_id` in the URL, but the issue here is that there is a separate _product feed_ created within the Product Catalog.

Comment: I ended up submitting a Facebook bug report as well and they're confirmed that this is a bug on their end: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1469859479724206/